# Can't access individual samba shares

Tags: linux, centos, samba, share

I've just installed CentOS and I'm configuring Samba. I have a share with the following in the smb.conf file:

```
[storage]
comment = Main storage for all use
path = /share
public = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
printable = no
write list = bob root
create mask = 0775
guest ok = yes
available = yes
```

In Windows Explorer, I can reach the page listing all the shares on the server, but I click on the shares themselves, I get an error saying that the folder cannot be found.

I have verified that the folder /share exists and I've also given it 777 permissions so it cannot be due to permissions.

What is causing this? I can post more config files if necessary.

Comment: Are you running SELINUX on this machine? If so, there are some notes on enabling directories to be used in samba shares in the smb.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "security = share" in the global section of smb.conf.

Comment: This did not correct the problem, sorry.